# How can i get all data in left table and related table data based on condition laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

[image]I have a product table with id ,name ,price and cart table with id ,user_id ,product_id ,qty.
I want all data in product table and related data in cart table where **user_id is logged user_id**.If no relation with cart i should get data in product table.

Table structure like this:

Comment: Hi! Kindly include your desired output in your description. And if possible the table structure with sample data also. Thank you

Comment: @ErrBon updated

Comment: It's better if you add the table structure as text not as an image..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example I think you want  something like:

```
create table product (
id int(9) not null auto_increment,
name varchar(20),
Primary key id(`id`)
);

insert into product values (1,'mobile'),(2,'tv'),(3,'fridge');

create table cart (
id int(9) not null auto_increment,
product_id int(9) ,
qty int(9) ,
user_id int(9) ,
Primary key id(`id`)
);

insert into cart values (1,1,1,1),(2,1,1,2);
```

And you should use:

```
select p.*,c.* from product p left join cart c on p.id=c.product_id and c.user_id=1;
```

[image]